# How to automatically change the bit value in sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Hi coder in my application i have some details which user fill, after entering details and press on submit button it will store in the database. I have bit value associated with that form so that when user enter details and click on submit button bit become true.

What i want is after one day that bit automatically become false how can i do that

Comment: Why not just store the last submitted date instead, and when you run your query simple compare `GetDate()` with that?

Comment: great minds think alike...

Comment: can i user timer control so that after some time bit automatically become false

Comment: wait guys let me update my question then reply just give 30 min

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't have a way to do "Elapsed-Time" triggers. You can only trigger a data change on Insert/Update/Delete and so on...

What I'd suggest is, instead of storing a bit value, store a `datetime` instead.

So when a user fills in your form, and ticks a box, don't store a bit value, instead set a `DateTime` column to `getdate()`

Then change whatever logic relies on this column to test to see if the value in the column is > 1 day away from the current time.

```
if( DateDiff(day, your_column, getdate()) >= 1 ) --more than 1 day has elapsed.
```

Comment: i know i m thinking of using times but dont know how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose a different approach.

This is what I would do:

Instead of storing an actual Boolean value I would store the Date and Time at which the click occurred. So instead of a `bit` column I would use a `Date` column.

Later on, when trying to determine (passively, not actively) whether a day has elapsed or not
I would subtract the stored value in that particular column from the current Date Time and check if it yield a whole day or not.

It goes something like this:

```
// instead of this
row[column] = true;
// do this
row[other_column] = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

and where you want to test the value:

```
// instead of this
if ((bool)row[column]) { ... }
// do this
DateTime dateAndTimeOfClick = (DateTime)row[other_column];
bool isStillTrue = DateTime.UtcNow - dateAndTimeOfClick < TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
if (isStillTrue) { ... }
```

Comment: see i have a date column in my table

Comment: Well you could have a load of date columns. Make sure you don't break any existing functionality. What happens with the date column ? What does it represent? If by coincidence it represents the last DateTime when the user clicked the submit button then your problem is solved half-way. If not, don't meddle with existing functionality. Try adding a new column. If it's not a good idea to add columns because you're working with legacy apps, try adding a new table with a foreign key pointing towards the rows in the "not to be meddled with" table and place your desired column there

Comment: when user click on submit button it pick the system date and time and store that time in the table

Comment: please understand that you didn't mention that particular detail. Read the answers I and @Eoin Campbell wrote. We both presumed you aren't already storing the date and time, so we gave you full answers on how to do it, including something which you are already doing... Bottom line is: Don't try to magically react to the passing of time because it's expensive and imprecise. Try to have a more passive, just-in-time, better later than earlier approach.